# paging3 state always stuck at the end of first page when navigating away

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

So, i was learning jetpack compose, and trying to make an anime index app which use paging3, pagingcompose,and lazy layout. But, even when i save the lazy state in rememberlazyliststate and rememberlazygridstate, the paging state is always stuck at the end of page 1, i also tried to restore state on compose navigation but still it didn't work as i expected.

Here is my code for flow and ui state on viewmodel:

```
 private val anime: Flow<PagingData<Anime>> = displayedAnimeType.flatMapLatest { type ->
    when (type) {
        DisplayType.POPULAR -> useCases.getPopularAnime().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        DisplayType.AIRING -> useCases.getAiringAnime().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        DisplayType.UPCOMING -> useCases.getUpcomingAnime().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        DisplayType.SEARCH -> searchedAnime.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}

val explorationScreenState: StateFlow<ExploreScreenState> =
    combine(
        headerState,
        displayedStyle,
        displayedAnimeType,
    ) { headerState: HeaderScreenState, displayedStyle: DisplayStyle, displayedType: DisplayType ->
        ExploreScreenState(
            headerScreenState = headerState,
            displayStyle = displayedStyle,
            displayType = displayedType,
            anime = anime
        )
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
        initialValue = ExploreScreenState()
    )
```

And here is my code for the lazy layout:

```
fun ExplorationScreen(
screenState: ExploreScreenState,
onEvent: (ExploreScreenEvent) -> Unit,
onAnimeClicked: (Anime) -> Unit,
modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
val pagingAnime: LazyPagingItems<Anime> = screenState.anime.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

val listOfLazyGridState: Map<DisplayType, LazyGridState> = mapOf(
    Pair(DisplayType.POPULAR, rememberLazyGridState()),
    Pair(DisplayType.AIRING, rememberLazyGridState()),
    Pair(DisplayType.UPCOMING, rememberLazyGridState())
)

val listOfLazyListState: Map<DisplayType, LazyListState> = mapOf(
    Pair(DisplayType.POPULAR, rememberLazyListState()),
    Pair(DisplayType.AIRING, rememberLazyListState()),
    Pair(DisplayType.UPCOMING, rememberLazyListState())
)
val lazyGridState = listOfLazyGridState[screenState.displayType]
val lazyListState = listOfLazyListState[screenState.displayType]

Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        // Top App Bar component
    },
    modifier = modifier
) { paddingValue ->

    if (pagingAnime.itemCount == 0 && screenState.displayType == DisplayType.SEARCH) {
        // Show error message when anime is not found on searching
        return@Scaffold
    }

    when (val refreshing = pagingAnime.loadState.refresh) {
        is LoadState.Error -> {
            // Show error message and retry button
            return@Scaffold
        }

        LoadState.Loading -> {
            // Show Loading Progress
            return@Scaffold
        }

        is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
            if (screenState.displayStyle == DisplayStyle.LIST) {
                LazyListAnime(
                    lazyListState = lazyListState ?: rememberLazyListState(),
                    pagingAnime = pagingAnime,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValue),
                    onAnimeClicked = onAnimeClicked
                )
            } else {
                LazyGridAnime(
                    lazyGridState = lazyGridState ?: rememberLazyGridState(),
                    pagingAnime = pagingAnime,
                    screenState = screenState,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValue),
                    onAnimeClicked = onAnimeClicked
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is there anything wrong with my way? and also my lazy layout feels really janky compared to xml. Here is the repository since i can't include everything in here: [Lelenime Repository](https://github.com/Kamil-Malik/Lelenime_Compose). The ui component was on Core:Common module and Feature module

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Paging library.
You can use following workaround at the moment

First create a extension function

```
@Composable
fun <T : Any> LazyPagingItems<T>.rememberLazyListState(): LazyListState {
    // After recreation, LazyPagingItems first return 0 items, then the cached items.
    // This behavior/issue is resetting the LazyListState scroll position.
    // Below is a workaround. More info: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177245496.
    return when (itemCount) {
        // Return a different LazyListState instance.
        0 -> remember(this) { LazyListState(0, 0) }
        // Return rememberLazyListState (normal case).
        else -> androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState()
    }
}
```

Then create lazyListState for your lazyPagingItems

```
val pagingAnimeScrollState = pagingAnime.rememberLazyListState()
```

Then in your lazyColumn pass this in `state` parameter.

This should fix your issue

Comment: But this method crash the app and didn't say any error except its function name

Comment: @lelestacia Can you share the exact crash log that got generated. Also your code with this change included. Could be that something is missed because it worked in my case

Comment: pardon me for not responding previously, i just tried it once again, It didn't crash this time, but still reset to the end of first page.